# What is more dangerous, exotoxins or endotoxins?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

Since gram- negative bacteria tends to cause disease to human and they mostly produce endotoxins. Does this mean that endotoxin is more dangerous than exotoxin? and if that so why?

Answer (score 0):

No. Exotoxins are more dangerous than endotoxins. endotoxins are made up of lipopolysaccharides, but exotoxins are made up of proteins, of which most are enzymes. due to the catalytic nature of enzymes, even a small amount of exotoxins can be dangerous (even micrograms of exotoxins can be dangerous).
[[differences between exotoxins and endotoxins](https://biodifferences.com/difference-between-endotoxin-and-exotoxin.html)][1](https://biodifferences.com/difference-between-endotoxin-and-exotoxin.html)